# postfix/dovecot filter who can send mail on behalf of

Tags: postfix, dovecot, users, filter

I am using postfix + dovecot(imap+pop3) + mysql
I whant to explicity define users or groups that can send email on behalf of others
I was thinking doing this way:
for all local(mysql) authenticated users filter outgoing mail:
filter all mail by headers Return-Path/X-Original-To/From: field must matche authenticated user that sends it, otherwise bounce the email

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [smtpd_sender_login_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps) and [reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch) in [smtpd_sender_restrictions](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_restrictions) to restrict which MAIL FROM addresses logged in users can use. For example:

main.cf:

```
smtpd_sender_login_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_login_maps
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch
```

/etc/postfix/sender_login_maps:

```
alice@example.com       alice
bob@example.com         bob
charlie@example.com     charlie
marketing@example.com   alice,charlie
```

Don't forget to run postmap:

```
# postmap /etc/postfix/sender_login_maps
```