# Dovecot Private User Login

Tags: security, dovecot, login

Is it possible to set up Dovecot in such a way that I can set up a "private" username that is associated with a public email address? For instance:

```
Email address : email@domain.com
Login username: ph97eWY2HvUW5jbBY3jmY6
```

This way, nobody would ever know what the actual username for email@domain.com is and attempts to login as email@domain.com would always fail.

For a 6 upper/lower/numeric character password you have 56.8M max combinations. A username with the same constraints would give 56.8M max combinations.

Assuming that an authentication system would tell you if the username was valid, using a secret password AND username would give a max combination of over 113M. In other words, if you had to guess both, it would take twice the effort at most to pass authentication.

If you (and the authentication system) treat a username as a password then the username IS a password! I can't believe I have to justify such a simple concept.

If it is possible to set up Dovecot a authentication method this way, please give instructions on how to accomplish this task.

Comment: Sure possible.. but what problem does that solve? Anyone attempting to login with invalid credentials will always fail.

Comment: And anyone who can steal your password can also steal your username. I see no point to this at all.

Comment: As a security measure that is not a very good one, but from a practical perspective, ; yes is very common that your login/account/user-name is different from email address(es) associated with your account.

Comment: @HBruijn Please qualify that statement. If it's considered a security measure to keep your password secret, how could you possibly argue that it would not be more secure to have a secret username?

Comment: @MichaelHampton What does stealing have anything to do with it? An intelligent person would know that the more information you can hide, the more secure your information. If a hacker knows your username, they only need to brute your password. If a hacker needs to brute your username, mathematically it will take at least twice as much effort to access the account.

Comment: @anx What problem does keeping your password secret solve? Logic dictates that a secret username would be twice as secure as only using a secret password.

Comment: @anx Can you link to a specific Q&A on SE? I think I'm going to have to prove my logic with a real-world challenge.

Comment: Why is there an option to disable SSH "root" user login? Could it be because it's the easiest user to find on a Linux system? If it's just as secure to allow a known user (root) to login as not, why does this option exist?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is either **avoid doing that** or **most of the configuration change is in your MTA**.

1. Adding complexity to the login name is [*worse* than adding the same amount of complexity to password](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/118414/88348), so please do not add this maintenance overhead for security reasons - there is no such benefit.
2. Separating login names from addresses for privacy reasons is also rather ineffective, as the recipient can correlate those mappings very easily. You could, however, remove login names from mail headers (see e.g. postfix option `header_checks`) - if you are willing to spend extra effort retrieving information that could have been easily accessible in headers.
3. If you need separate login names and usernames to deal with some legacy requirements or facilitate a migration in addresses without previously updating all clients, configuring those is almost trivial - in your MTA. Since dovecot userdb has no requirement for home directories, login names and mail addresses to match in any way, you are free to change your dovecot usernames as required.

   Assuming you use *postfix*, keep the login@domain.example format and already have `reject_authenticated_senderlogin_mismatch` in your `smtpd_sender_restrictions`, you just need to change or add `sender_login_maps` ([to define who can send from which email](https://serverfault.com/q/383392/250204)) and `virtual_alias_maps` (to define who receives which emails). The right hand side of those two maps then contains your dovecot user names.